# Application reading information from SQL databases : required / optional classes and methods?

Tags: android, sql, cursor, adapter, helper

I am working on an application whose purpose is to display a listview whose content will depend on which button the user clicks, and whose data come from a sql databse. It means my database will be using a "readable" attribute only, no need to change information from the database.
So, to learn how to do it, I am reading and doing lot of tutorials and i feel a bit lost about what is really required and what is optional in the design of the application.
Here is why. I have learned that to do so, my app will need:
- a ----Helper class (extending SQLiteOpenHelper)
- a ----Adapter class (to define my methods and queries for the database)
- a ----Table class (one class for each table of my database)
- my MainActivity (in my case, extending ListActivities)

And then, i found out that to do so I also need :
 - CursorLoader
 - ContentProvider
- fillData()

Every time I try to learn more, I find out about more and more classes or methods to use, it seems endless and I don't know if I really need to have that many classes for my application.
If someone can tell me if it seems right to have that many things, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to have a high level overview of what exactly you are going to do with the database and **how**. And, what you have figured out is almost correct.

Basic  Steps for any DB app in android are :

1. You will require `Helper` class, using which you can `create or upgrade` database along with `tables`.
2. Once you have database ready, there is a need for the class which will contain the data that you need to save in the database.
3. And lastly, there will be a class which will fire queries and retrieve data from database.
4. Till here, all backend functions are complete. Now you need to display the data that you have retrieved from db. For which, you use another class(in your class, one which extends `ListActivity`).

Don't get overwhelmed by number of classes, all the functionalities are kept in separate classes just to avoid cluttered code. But the basic steps remain same !

```
    And then, i found out that to do so I also need :
    - CursorLoader
    - ContentProvider
    - fillData()
```

Yes, these are different things that you could use to perform required function, like `ContentProvider` is used if you want to share data with other applications. So just figure out if you want to do that, and then only move ahead. Else the basic steps are enough.

Hope this helps!

You may refer a very nice tutorial on this : **http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html**

Comment: Thanks, it does help make me feel I am on the right way. Will read the tutorial now!